# SMS online sending service

Tags: ios, service, sms

I'm looking for an online sms sending service, that I can use within my iOS-App.
My aim is to send a verification code to the phone number, the user provided.
In Android its not too big of a deal, since I can send sms programmatically, but in iOS 
I can't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our app we use http://www.twilio.com/ to send SMS through a service on the iPhone, its pretty great.

For sending SMSs you don't even need to download their SDK and put it into your project. It basically comes down to a HTTP POST command in which you provide the phone number to SMS, the message body, and your API key+secret.

Here is an example for your convenience on sending an SMS through Twillio:

```
- (void)twilloSendSMS:(NSString *)message withQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
           andSID:(NSString *)SID andSecret:(NSString *)secret
    andFromNumber:(NSString *)from andToNumber:(NSString *)to {
    NSLog(@"Sending request.");

    // Build request
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/SMS/Messages", SID, secret, SID];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Set up the body
    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From=%@&To=%@&Body=%@", from, to, message];
    NSData *data = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil && ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200 ||     [httpResponse statusCode] == 201))
         {

             NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Request sent. %@", receivedString);

     }
     else {
             NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Request sent. %@", receivedString);
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: and then I simply call the function you provided above?

Comment: Yeah, you essentially just need to signup for the service, and you can play around with the function I provided. At the beginning you get one test number (which is your number) that you can send to, for free, just to test the service out. So you can try sending to that phone number with some "hello world" message body, and see that its all working.

Comment: But when I want to send to various numbers, it costs?

Comment: Yes it does, you can check out their price range here: http://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing

Comment: Okay and i guess there is no free service ?

Comment: Well essentially you cannot send text messages programatically on iOS so the only way is to get a service that sends the messages for you. I am not aware of any free services as of right now. However, Twillio does offer very good pricing, and airbnb uses it as well. Worth a shot if you want this to work easily, low cost, and well.

Comment: yes I guess, but in my case it really is a low budget production, so I will leave the activation code out for ios and only provide it for android

Comment: Not to be a debbie downer but you really shouldn't have your "secret" stored on the client. Anything stored on the client is inherently not secret since someone could easily decompile your app and obtain your "secret." Other than that, thanks for the tip.